# How can I check if user-entered email is already saved in my database before submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I want to check whether the e-mail entered by the user in the form has already been saved in the database. I got help from Chatgpt, but I still couldn't do it, it runs the form completely without checking the entered information and adds it directly to the database.

**register.html**

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" method="POST" action="mysql/kayitekle.php" id="login-form">
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-3">
                        Kayıt Ol
                    </span>
                    <div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                        <label for="name" class="txt1">
                            İsim
                                                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "İsim alanı gereklidir">
                        <input id="name" class="input100" type="text" name="name" >
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="p-t-31 p-b-9">
                        <label for="email" class="txt1">
                            E-posta Adresi
                            <span class="text-danger" id="email-message"></span>                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "E-posta adresi gereklidir">
                        <input id="email" class="input100" type="email" name="email" >
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="p-t-13 p-b-9 d-inline-flex">
                        <label for="password" class="txt1">
                            Şifre
                            <span class="text-danger" id="password-message"></span>                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Şifre alanı gereklidir">
                        <input id="password" class="input100" type="password" name="password" >
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="p-t-13 p-b-9 d-inline-flex">
                        <label for="password_confirmation" class="txt1">
                            Şifre
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Şifre alanı gereklidir">
                        <input id="password_confirmation" class="input100" type="password" name="password_confirmation" >
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-17">
                        <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn" id="submit">
                            Kayıt Ol
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w-full text-center p-t-55">
                        <span class="txt2">
                            Zaten üye misin?
                        </span>

                        <a href="#" class="txt2 bo1">
                            Hemen giriş yap!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>

<script>
        const frm = document.getElementById("login-form");
        frm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
      
          const messageElement = document.getElementById("email-message");
          const email = document.getElementById("email").value;

      
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
              const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              const exists = response.exists;
      
              if (exists) {
                messageElement.innerHTML = "E-MAIL is already registered";
              } else {
                // Kayıt işlemi devam edebilir
                frm.submit();
              }
            }
          };
      
          xhr.open("POST", "kontrolet.php", true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          xhr.send("email=" + encodeURIComponent(email));
        });
      </script>
```

**kontrolet.php**

```
<?php

include("baglanti.php");
$eposta = $_POST["email"];

// Veritabanı bağlantısı

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM uyehesap WHERE email = '$eposta'";
$result = mysqli_query($baglan, $query);

if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $exists = true;
}

$response = array("exists" => $exists);
echo json_encode($response);

// Bağlantıyı kapat
mysqli_close($baglan);
?>
```

I want to check whether the e-mail entered by the user in the form is saved in the database, but it saves it to the database without checking it directly.

Comment: Where's the code that saves the form's data to the database?

Comment: You'd need to use AJAX if you want to check "_before submitting the form_"

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: you have 2 things to do. First, you make a php function to check if email exist (return true or false). You make a javascript function on the onchange of the email input, when change you check

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to say can only be archived using AJAX. But if you wanna check on form submit and return back an error based on the result, you can achieve that by adding the following code.

```
// Check if the email already exists
$query = "SELECT * FROM your_database WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    return false; // Email already registered
}
```

Secondly, right now your SQL code is really unsafe. Your current code directly takes user input in the SQL query. Which can easily result in SQL Injection. Always Sanitize your from inputs.

Lastly, I will recommend you to use **prepared statements or parameterized queries** to make your Database more safe.